# AngularJS: routing not working using ng click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For my app, i have a login page that serves as index.html. Based on the user login, the app routes to different landing pages.

However, within one of the landing pages, I am routing to another page by using ng click and it does not fire. What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible that I can't route to another page from a landing page if the app is being served by index.html since the paths are absolute URLs?

In summary: I have 3 pages in my app: index.html (login page) and page1.html and page2.html. When the user logs into the app, he lands on page1.html. From here if he clicks a button then he should be sent to page2.html. 
    A working plunker would be highly appreciated.

Here is what I have in user1.html

User1.html

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
-----
</head>

<header>
-------
</header>

<body ng-controller="TestController">
<button ng-click="go('/user1')">Link</button>
------------------------------------------------------
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../webjars/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])



    app.config([
                "$routeProvider","$locationProvider" ,
                function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
                    $routeProvider.when('/user1',{
                        templateUrl:"../html/page2.html",
                        controller: 'TestController'
                    });

                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            }
        ]);

    app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$location',function($scope, $location){ 
        $scope.go = function (hash) { 
        $location.path(hash);
         };
    }
]);

})();
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8VdQIZDHcX36WhuKbAev

Comment: *"A working plunker would be highly appreciated"* - a plunker with code working so far which we can modify will be highly appreciated from your side as well.

Comment: why are you using angularjs 1.3.8 and 1.2.20 both together? `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../webjars/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>`

Comment: @T J added plunker link